# How to make a trigger reversible in a rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, triggers, migration

I'm writing a migration in Ruby on Rails contains triggers and when I rolled back I got the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration: 

This migration uses execute, which is not automatically reversible.
To make the migration reversible you can either:
1. Define #up and #down methods in place of the #change method.
2. Use the #reversible method to define reversible behavior.
```

I defined all tables and triggers in a change function:

```
class Geolocation < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
    def change
     [...]
     execute <<-SQL
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION zone_preset_jolly_city() RETURNS trigger
        LANGUAGE plpgsql AS 
        $$BEGIN
          INSERT INTO cities( zone_preset_id, name ) VALUES ( NEW.zone_id, '%' );
          RETURN NEW;
        END;$$;

        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION city_jolly_toponym() RETURNS trigger
        LANGUAGE plpgsql AS 
        $$BEGIN
          INSERT INTO toponyms( city_id, toponym_type_id, name ) VALUES ( NEW.city_id, '%', '%' );
          RETURN NEW;
        END;$$;

        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION toponym_jolly_street_number() RETURNS trigger
        LANGUAGE plpgsql AS 
        $$BEGIN
          INSERT INTO street_numbers( toponym_id, number ) VALUES ( NEW.toponym_id, '%' );
          RETURN NEW;
        END;$$; 

        CREATE TRIGGER zone_preset_jolly
          AFTER INSERT ON zone_presets
          FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE zone_preset_jolly_city();

        CREATE TRIGGER city_jolly_toponym
          AFTER INSERT ON cities
          FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE city_jolly_toponym();

        CREATE TRIGGER toponym_jolly_street_number
          AFTER INSERT ON toponyms
          FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE toponym_jolly_street_number();
      SQL
end
```

So I'm trying to define an up and a down function to correctly revert the triggers but I don't know how to do define them reversed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about making the data changes in the migration reversable, then just rename your change method to `up` and make an empty down method:

```
class Geolocation < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]

  # this used to be def change
  def up
    ...
    ...
  ...
  end

  def down
  end
end
```

If you do care about making it reversible, then you'll need to inverse whatever transactions you perform in the up method and run them in your down method. But of course not everything will be fully reversible.

Answer (score 1):

I like using reversible in those cases.

```rb
class MigrationName < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    reversible do |dir|
      dir.up do
        execute <<-SQL
          INSERT INTO users VALUES ('name');
        SQL
      end

      dir.down do
        execute <<-SQL
          DELETE FROM users;
        SQL
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers! I fixed it and here it is the full example for other people who need it:

```
def change
[...]

 reversible do |dir|
   dir.up do
     execute <<-SQL
       CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION zone_preset_jolly_city() RETURNS trigger
       LANGUAGE plpgsql AS 
       $$BEGIN
         INSERT INTO cities( zone_preset_id, name ) VALUES ( NEW.zone_id, '%' );
         RETURN NEW;
       END;$$;

       CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION city_jolly_toponym() RETURNS trigger
       LANGUAGE plpgsql AS 
       $$BEGIN
         INSERT INTO toponyms( city_id, toponym_type_id, name ) VALUES ( NEW.city_id, '%', '%' );
         RETURN NEW;
       END;$$;

       CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION toponym_jolly_street_number() RETURNS trigger
       LANGUAGE plpgsql AS 
       $$BEGIN
         INSERT INTO street_numbers( toponym_id, number ) VALUES ( NEW.toponym_id, '%' );
         RETURN NEW;
       END;$$; 

       CREATE TRIGGER zone_preset_jolly
         AFTER INSERT ON zone_presets
         FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE zone_preset_jolly_city();

       CREATE TRIGGER city_jolly_toponym
         AFTER INSERT ON cities
         FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE city_jolly_toponym();

       CREATE TRIGGER toponym_jolly_street_number
         AFTER INSERT ON toponyms
         FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE toponym_jolly_street_number();
     SQL
   end

   dir.down do
     execute <<-SQL
       DROP TRIGGER toponym_jolly_street_number ON toponyms;
       DROP TRIGGER city_jolly_toponym ON cities;
       DROP TRIGGER zone_preset_jolly ON zone_presets;
     SQL
   end
 end
end
```